# How to split a HTML files into chapters?

Tags: html

I have an HTML file. I want to create several smaller HTML files (with chapters) and ToC.

Which software does this?

I am interested in free, portable software.

Comment: For what OS? What price is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT program: [HTML-split](https://www.openhub.net/p/htmlsplit) (you need an XSLT 2.0 processor like [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to run it, Saxon in turn requires Java) splits an XHTML file into several chapters and creates a table of contents. It works on all modern OSes.

HTML-split is fully customizable and themeable with XML templates, so that you can create a custom designed Web site from your HTML ebook.

It supports only XHTML. If you need to split a regular HTML file, first convert in into XHTML format by [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) program.

All aforementioned software is free.

Comment: Well, repeating half of my comment on your question: What OS(es) are supported by this solution(s)? ;)